# Importing POS orders to OpenERP 6.1 pos back-end

Tags: odoo

I am trying to import orders from an external Pos system to Pos-backend in OpenErp 6.1 using the Import-Export Tools of OpenErp. I use a import compatible model and all the orders could be imported without any problem (order, payments, journals, accounts, i.e the completed orders.)

In the list of POS ORDERS, the state of imported orders is NEW. For the imported orders to be treated by the system and to change the order status to PAID, you may delete the order payments manually, and do MAke Payment for each order. The Import Tools does not hanle automaticly the imported orders. is there any way to batch process the imported pos orders?
Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script to import data from one database to another database.

```
import xmlrpclib
from osv import osv, fields

#To create connection to the database from where you want to import data
def connect_server(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8070/xmlrpc/common', encoding="UTF-8")
    remote_uid = sock_common.login(database_name, user_name, password)
    sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8070/xmlrpc/object', encoding="UTF-8")
return (sock, remote_uid)


#Fetch data from another database
def get_data(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    sock, remote_uid = self.connect_server(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    pos_order_obj = self.pool.get('pos.order')
    pos_order_ids = sock.execute(db_name, remote_uid, password, pos_order_obj._name, 'search', [])
    for pos in in sock.execute(db_name, remote_uid, password, pos_order_obj._name, 'read', pos_order_ids, []):
        #fetch the data and create record in your current database.
        new_pos_val = {'name': pos['name'],}
        pos_order_obj.create(cr, uid, new_pos_val, context=context)
     return True
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Arya, But my problem is not to import the orders. I can easily import the orders( order headers, order lines, and payments)using Import utility for .csv files. but I am looking to create a button on pos back-end to process  POS imported orders with the Draft state with the same procedure as you enter the payment for an order in point-of-sale page by pressing validate button. As I undrestand to to batch process of these orders using check method of pos_make_payment class: